# Authentication with Azure Active Directory on App Service for multi-container app (docker-compose)

Tags: azure, authentication, docker-compose, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to enable in-build authentication for app service with Azure Active Directory.

It is working fine when I use single container configuration, but when I try to configure docker-compose then the redirection to microsoft login page is not in place.

I am using nginx (reverse-proxy image) for serving the static websites (two images) and one api image (server image).

App service in-build authentication is enabled and Active Directory is configured and action to take when request is not authenticated is set to Log in with Azure Active Directory.
[screenshot of auth setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WmKG.png)

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    image: plugotestcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/server:latest
    environment:
      PORT: 4000
    expose:
      - "4000"
    restart: always
  reverse-proxy:
    image: plugotestcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/reverse-proxy:latest
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
```

nginx config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root   /usr/share/nginx/root;
  location / {
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  location /api {
    proxy_pass  "http://api:4000";
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
  location /admin {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/admin/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Working authentication using AAD and docker compose in Web App for containers.